# Connector type for precision PT100?

Tags: connector, temperature, interconnect

Any advice on how to choose connectors for a 4 wire PT100 (plus shield)? Bearing in mind this is a precision measurement using [1/10 DIN RTD standard](http://www.temperature.com.au/Support/RTDSensors/RTDaccuracyClassAClassB13DIN110DIN.aspx), and I'm concerned about thermocouple effects, etc. I would also like a socket that connects directly to the PCB to eliminate yet another set of wiring and connectors going to the bulkhead. Any suggestions on what to look for?

Comment: And before anyone asks, yes, the layout does take into account dissimilar metals and thermal gradients created by various components

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 4-wire measurement practically anything good quality suitable for low level connections will work. Thermoelectric effects only are a concern if there is a serious temperature *gradient* across the connector, and a few ohms of resistance will not affect the reading if the circuit design is good.

Examples of suitable connectors include Lemo, military style 38999 circular connectors, Mxx connectors and even good quality (preferably screw-machine and definitely gold-plated) D-connectors. Some audio connectors are probably also suitable.

To minimize thermocouple effects, choose the pinout (as much as possible) so that the sense connections are close together and symmetric mechanically. The force wires don't matter. So if you were to be using a connector with two rows, pick top and bottom near the center for the sense wires. That will minimize the effect of local temperature gradients at the connector. Of course if you were using AC or reversing DC measurements the T/C effects could be cancelled out completely, but that's far from necessary under normal conditions for Pt100 1/10 DIN. We are currently doing single-digit micro-Kelvin measurements with specialized RTDs- the signals pass through several types of connectors on the way to the sensor- including many of the types I've mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. I have now got a more specific answer and very similar from the engineering company that builds our custom PT100 sensors.

Comment: What have you found out from the custom PT100 company?  What are they recommending?